# private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter; what does this line do? i m beginner of Android

Tags: android

Actually I m beginner of Android. Kindly help me to describe what does this line do?
 private ArrayAdapter listAdapter;
 what is purpose of ArrayAdapter ListAdapter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300661/please-explain-array-adapters-and-their-purpose-even-better

Answer (score 0):

ListView populates data using an Adapter. The simplest adapter to use is called an ArrayAdapter because the adapter converts an ArrayList of objects into View items loaded into the ListView.